# Ford-Fulkerson for maximum cardinality matchings

Tags: graph-theory, optimization, algorithms, network, network-flow

If I have a bipartite graph $G(V_1 \cup V_2)$ and I wanted to find the maximum matching. Why is it that the ford-fulkerson algorithm will take at most $min{(|V_1|,|V_2|)}$ iterations? I know that in each iteration it will find an augmenting path from source to sink, but I do not understand the limits on the number of iterations.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Each iteration increases the cardinality of the match by at least one, so that it can't run more rounds than the number of vertices on the smaller of the two sides because matching is one-to-one.